# ask for a split function in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

right now there is a string like this:
    789+456-239

I want to get a list like this:

```
sign | num
+      789
+      456
-      239
```

Comment: you want it sign and num as columns?

Comment: And the string doesn't start with a `+` but you still want that displayed? What other formatting glitches will you want to handle? `+-`? `--`? `789+456-`?

Comment: if there isn't a sing on the left of the number, the default sign is "+", don't consider +-, -- and any other like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a way, by using a commonly used split string method, just adapted to your need to handle the sign.

```
-- test case
with yourString(str) as 
        (
        select '+789+456-239 ' str
        from dual
        )
-- query
SELECT regexp_substr(str, '[+-]', 1, level) sign,
       regexp_substr(str, '[^+-]+', 1, level) num
  FROM ( select case                                  
                  when substr(str, 1, 1) in ('+','-') then str
                  -- I add a plus sign if the first char of the string is not a sign
                  else '+' || str 
                end as str
         from yourString
       )
CONNECT BY regexp_instr(str, '[+-]', 1, level ) > 0
```

This gives:

```
SIGN           NUM
-------------- --------------
+              789
+              456
-              239
```

Here I assume that if no sign is given in the beginning of this string, the first sign will be `+`.

If you need to handle more than one string, you need to identify an ID in your table and the `CONNECT BY` becomes a bit more complex:

```
-- test case
with yourString(id, str) as 
        (
        select 1, '+789+456-239' from dual union all
        select 2, '789+456-239'  from dual union all
        select 3, '-789+456-239' from dual
        )
-- query
SELECT id,
       regexp_substr(str, '[+-]', 1, level) sign,
       regexp_substr(str, '[^+-]+', 1, level) num
  FROM ( select id,
                case                                  
                  when substr(str, 1, 1) in ('+','-') then str
                  -- I add a plus sign if the first char of the string is not a sign
                  else '+' || str 
                end as str
         from yourString
       )
CONNECT BY regexp_instr(str, '[+-]', 1, level ) > 0
  and prior id = id
  and prior sys_guid() is not null
```

The result:

```
       ID SIGN  NUM
---------- ----- --------------------------------------------
         1 +     789
         1 +     456
         1 -     239
         2 +     789
         2 +     456
         2 -     239
         3 -     789
         3 +     456
         3 -     239
```

Comment: There is an issue if the input table has multiple rows that the hierarchical query will not know which hierarchical row it generates to correlate with which parent row and will generate exponential numbers of duplicate rows as it correlates each successive level with all possible parents.

Comment: Also, you only need `[+-]` for the regular expression - otherwise you are matching either `+` or `-` or \.

Comment: @MT0 Just added a version to handle more than one string. About the regexp, you're right, thanks, just fixed. I thouught I needed to escape the minus sign within the `[]`, that's why I used the `'\'`.

Comment: I like `CROSS APPLY` for row generators for multiple input rows.  It isolates the complexity of the row generator from the rest of the query and allows for the simpler `CONNECT BY` form ... no `sys_guid()` or `dbms_random` hack.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method that does not use regular expressions and can handle multiple input rows:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a0ac1/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, list ) AS
  SELECT 1, '789+456-239' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '-123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '+456' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '789' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH bounds ( id, list, start_pos, end_pos, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         list,
         1,
         CASE 
         WHEN INSTR( list, '+', 2 ) = 0 THEN INSTR( list, '-', 2 )
         WHEN INSTR( list, '-', 2 ) = 0 THEN INSTR( list, '+', 2 )
         ELSE LEAST( INSTR( list, '+', 2 ), INSTR( list, '-', 2 ) )
         END,
         1
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         list,
         end_pos,
         CASE 
         WHEN INSTR( list, '+', end_pos + 1 ) = 0 THEN INSTR( list, '-', end_pos + 1 )
         WHEN INSTR( list, '-', end_pos + 1 ) = 0 THEN INSTR( list, '+', end_pos + 1 )
         ELSE LEAST( INSTR( list, '+', end_pos + 1 ), INSTR( list, '-', end_pos + 1 ) )
         END,
         lvl + 1
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
)
SELECT id,
       DECODE( SUBSTR( list, start_pos, 1 ), '-', '-', '+' ) AS sign,
       SUBSTR(
         list,
         start_pos + DECODE( SUBSTR( list, start_pos, 1 ), '-', 1, '+', 1, 0 ),
         DECODE( end_pos, 0, LENGTH( list ) + 1, end_pos ) - start_pos - DECODE( SUBSTR( list, start_pos, 1 ), '-', 1, '+', 1, 0 )
       ) AS item,
      lvl
FROM   bounds
ORDER BY id, lvl
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a0ac1/2/0)**:

```
| ID | SIGN | ITEM | LVL |
|----|------|------|-----|
|  1 |    + |  789 |   1 |
|  1 |    + |  456 |   2 |
|  1 |    - |  239 |   3 |
|  2 |    - |  123 |   1 |
|  3 |    + |  456 |   1 |
|  4 |    + |  789 |   1 |
```